# issue firing off wcf service to send xml file

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I new to wcf however i'm attempting to use net.tcp binding wcf service to transmit an xml file to the client.

I can get up to creating the xml file and upon attempting to connect to my wcf service fails.

I followed this guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx up to creating the windows test app, i'm using a web project for this.

I have added the service reference to project and below is the code i'm attempting to execute:

```
public string SendXMLDocument(XmlDocument xDoc)
        {
var message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "Request_for_action", new XmlNodeReader(xDoc));

            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IActionServiceLibrary>("IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.IActionServiceLibrary");
            var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

            var response = channel.Request(message);
            channel.Close();

            return response.ToString(); //this should come back okay..

        }
```

my library appconfig looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8080/ActionService/" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IActionServiceLibrary" contract="IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.IActionServiceLibrary"
        name="IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.IActionServiceLibrary">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.ActionServiceLibrary">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8080/ActionService/" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.IActionServiceLibrary">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8080/ActionService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Action_Service" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
          listenBacklog="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" portSharingEnabled="false">
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IActionServiceLibrary" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

the app config for the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8080/ActionService/" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IActionServiceLibrary" contract="IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.IActionServiceLibrary"
        name="IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.IActionServiceLibrary">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.ActionServiceLibrary">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8080/ActionService/" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMMS.ActionsServiceLibrary.IActionServiceLibrary">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8080/ActionService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Action_Service" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
          listenBacklog="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" portSharingEnabled="false">
          <reliableSession enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IActionServiceLibrary" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

i get a name mismatch on the channel creation.

any help to point me in the right direction for transmitting a xml file through wcf would be great.

Comment: this thing wouldn't let me edit it but if you see SITA.IMMS it's just IMMS now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my config file was messed up after fixing the errors it works now.